# need zend_auth in bootstrap

Tags: zend-framework

in my _initLogger function in the Bootstrap file, I want to also log the user's ID. I though doing it with zend_auth, but this does not seem to work. I get no error but neither an user ID.

Does anyone has a solution? Regards

Comment: Why not log the id's only when the login process begins ?

Answer (score 2):

Dont use the bootstrap, bootstrap is for getting ready. U problably wont to use a fc-plugin..